# Display the current time during a PDF slides presentation (i.e., totally full screen)

Tags: pdf, okular

I want to have current time (i.e., HH:MM) displayed in a corner of the screen when I present my slides (at the moment, I'm using Okular but I'm open to change).

I have found a working solution

```
$ cat ~/bin/clock
font=${1:-'-etl-fixed-medium-r-normal--40-400-72-72-c-200-iso8859-1'}
while true ; do
    date +%H:%M | osd_cat -f "$font" -s 2 -A right -c gray80 -O 1 -d 60
done
```

but I'd prefer if my PDF viewer itself takes charge of the issue of displaying the time when in presentation mode.

As far as I can tell, Okular doesn't have this option, but I may be wrong... hence my question is twofold

- Does Okular support showing time while in presentation mode?
- Does it exist another PDF viewer that supports showing time while in presentation mode?